# How do I avoid the other kendo filters clearing from filter type date?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've been google around and searching through the kendo docs for a little while now.I can't find anything about why my other filters are clearing. Below is my column piece for kendo. The filterType date clears any other filters I may have applied previously. I need it be filter type date because I want the user to pick a date from a calender if they want to.

```
schema: { data: "Test", total: "tTest", model: { fields: { Field5: { type: "date" } } } }
columns: [
    { field: "Field1", title: "Field1", width: "60px" },
    { field: "Field2", title: "Field2", width: "70px" },
    { field: "Field3", title: "Field3", width: "40px" },
    { field: "Field4", title: "Field4", width: "100px" },
    { field: "Field5", title: "Field5, width: "60px", filterType: 'Date', format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" }
 ],
```

Why is this clearing my other filters? I would like to note, I am doing server filtering. The moment I take a way the filterType it works like a charm.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it. It may not be correct and I still don't know why it did it originally but i changed filterType: 'Date' to filterable: {ui: "datepicker"} and altered the format of the date as it came in.

Thanks,
Anthony